# What do these 'smbclient' samba information mean?

Tags: windows, samba

On a gentoo Linux I am making a call to `smbclient`, which among others show the following output when it is connecting to a Windows share on a Windows machine:

```
Domain=[LN_DOMAIN] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.24]
```

What do these information tell me? Especially, what is the number '3.6.24' in the last part? It looks like a version number, but `/usr/bin/smbclient -V` returns:

```
Version 3.0.33
```

So what does the number `3.6.24` mean? There does not seem to be anything on the man pages.

Full example to reproduce this outcome (run on the Linux client, to list the content of a directory on Windows, like Windows7 or Windows XP):

```
/usr/bin/smbclient "//123.123.123.123/Backup" "password" -U "username"  -W "workspace" -D "Directory" -c "ls"
```

Answer (score 1):

That `3.6.24` is the version of the Samba server you are connecting to. That doesn't have to be the same version as the client that runs locally.

On the server run:

```
smbstatus
```

to get the version info for the server samba.

Your client version seems to be from [2008](http://www.samba.org/samba/history/samba-3.0.33.html), so maybe you should consider updating it.

Comment: So, there is something running on the (Windows) Server that has a version of 3.6.24? What exactly is it? Is it also just a 'samba' version running on Windows?

Comment: @Alex I assumed you were connecting via Samba to another Unix/Linux box (on 123.123.123.123) with Samba. Let me see if I can get that kind of response from Windows

Comment: @Alex when I try that with a Windows server I get: `Server=[Windows Server 2003 R2 5.2]`, can you double check that IP address?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. So maybe this 'response' depends on the configuration on the Windows box. But I have TWO cases in which I am quite sure the server is Windows, and in both cases the 'response' is always something like `Server=[Samba 3.x.y]`.

Comment: @Alex I actually have only one windows server to try. It looks like you can run [Samba on Windows](http://smithii.com/samba) But I am not sure why one would do that.

Comment: To be able to copy files from Linux to Windows?

Comment: @Alex for that you don't need to install the samba server on your windows box. It comes (or at least the Professional versions of Windows) with built in support for the SMB/CIFS protocol that Samba (on Linux) talks against.

Comment: And this has the version 3.6.24? Why do I then get a different string than you get?

Comment: @Alex No, I just tested `smbclient` against a machine that I know 100% sure is a Windows machine. I only get `Server=[Samba X.Y.Z]` if I run smbclient against my Linux server running Samba.

Comment: You are probably right. The server I am using seems to be Linux and not Windows. Thanks so far...

Comment: @Alex That is why asked to double check the IP address >:-). Glad you made some progress.